# Initial login request using auth_type=reauthenticate results in browser warning

Tags: authentication, facebook-authentication, facebook-login

I need to force an explicit login through facebook with each new session. I am using auth_type=reauthenticate as documented here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reauthentication/

However, firefox and safari give me a non-secure form warning after the user attempts to log in.  (Firefox: "Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent of an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party"...)

Here's my call:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?auth_type=reauthenticate&client_id=12345&redirect_uri=https://www.returnurl.com

Any way around this?

Comment: In the normal authentication process the Facebook oauth dialogue issues a GET redirect to http://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request which doesn't trigger the warning. When you use auth_type=reauthenticate that same URL is hit with a POST request. It seems to be this that triggers the warning.Facebook's own example code at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/reauthentication/ suffers from the same problem which suggests Osi and I aren't doing something completely foolish.

Comment: Need more info about how you are doing this.  Client side or server side flow?  In any case, check the action URL for the Form that is presented for the user to submit their password.  That URL has to be HTTPS, not HTTP.  If that URL is coming from Facebook and is not HTTPS, than it's a bug that they need to fix.

Comment: Are you including an `auth_nonce`? (You definitely should be and maybe that will help.)  Did you try using  `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize` instead of `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth`?

Comment: Yep, I'm using a nonce. The url is on Facebook's form and that's where the http is coming from (SO stripped the http bit of the link I posted above so I see that isn't clear, sorry).

Comment: ... and yes, it's the same with `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize` used in place of `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth`.